# How do I get a colored clan tag?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

How do I earn a colored clan tag in Modern Warfare 3?

I've seen a number of them, and I've heard you can get them from gaining a Prestige level a number of times or something like that.

Comment: In Black Ops, reaching a certain prestige rewarded you with colored tags. As @EBongo said, in MW3 it is a clan benefit.

Answer (score 7):

Other than exploits, the only colored clan tag I am aware of is the one that is a benefit to clans enrolled in the Call of Duty Elite service.  Clans on Elite earn experiences similar to what you earn as an individual, by completing periodic "clan challenges".  A full list of Clan prestige benefits for each level is [here](http://genetichax.com/mw3-clans/15189-call-duty-elite-clan-unlocks.html).  As you can see, level 10 unlocks a "Gold" clan tag.